# is it possible to store user time in utc time with timezone offset in the PostgreSQL DatetimeColumn

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I wanted to store user time in UTC but timezone information as an offset(i.e. user timezone) so I created a Postgres engine like this

```
db_uri = app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]
engine = create_engine(db_uri, connect_args={"options": "-c timezone={}".format(dtWithZone.timetz().tzinfo.zone)})
```

the output of `dtWithZone.timetz().tzinfo.zone` is `America/Tijuana`!

but when I punch this to heroku postgresql db Datetime column the time zone is  UTC time with +0:00 offset. I was hoping this to be utc time with user time zone .

Is it possible or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: postgres has `timestamptz` type, which is what you look for

Comment: Note that `timestamptz` does ***not*** store any timezone information. It simply normalizes all input to UTC. If you need the original timezone of the input you need a second column in your table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then how should a take Daylight savings into account when they are on ?

Comment: That will be taken care of when converting _from_ UTC to the timezone you want to display. Do read the manual, it's all explained there

Comment: So you are recommending that I should store timezone separate column ? would it be ok to store date time and timezone as a string Column ?